# jQuery scrollTo fixed header offset

Tags: jquery, offset, scrollto

I am using the jQuery scrollTo plugin as you can see on the page which I'm building http://portfolio.tomvervoort.net/

Because of the 300px fixed header the content moves under the header. You can see this clearly when you click the about button in the menu. Is it possible to add an 300px offset to the scrollTo script so everything stays positioned under the header/menu?

Comment: Can we have the code in the question please so the abbreviated answer below makes sense!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try changing this line in jquery.nav.js:

```
$.scrollTo(newLoc, o.scrollSpeed, {
```

to

```
$.scrollTo($('newLoc').offset().top-300, o.scrollSpeed, {
```

So instead of telling `scrollto` to scroll to exactly that element, you get the position of the element yourself and subtract 300

Comment: Awesome, Worked like a charm!

Comment: Makes no sense without context

Comment: @ChrisPink i think it's not too hard to figure out the context from the answer even if the website from the question isn't online any more

Answer (score 21):

You can use the "offset" setting as described on:

http://flesler.blogspot.com.ar/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Something like:

```
$.scrollTo(newLoc, o.scrollSpeed, {
     // ...
     offset:-300
});
```